# On CentOS7: Uninstalling mariadb-server also uninstalls php-mysql package

Tags: php, mariadb

**On CentOS7**: I need to upgrade **MariaDB** from **5.5** to **10.4**

I followed this guide: https://itcloudnet.blogspot.com/2019/10/how-to-upgrade-mariadb-55-to-mariadb.html but instructions on other sites are similar.

When I do

```
yum remove mariadb-server mariadb-devel mariadb-libs mariadb
```

I get

```
Removing:
 mariadb
 mariadb-devel
 mariadb-libs
 mariadb-server
Removing for dependencies:
 perl-DBD-MySQL
 php-mysql
 postfix
```

Then I proceed with the instructions and do

```
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

and the output is

```
Installing:
 MariaDB-client
 MariaDB-server
Installing for dependencies:
 MariaDB-common
 MariaDB-compat
 boost-program-options
 galera-4
```

So, no `php-mysql` here. And the biggest mystery of all is that the PHP web applications using MariaDB **still work**!

**How come?** So, after all, do I need the package `php-mysql` or not?

Some clarifications:

1. I use the standard Apache that comes with **CentOS7** `httpd-2.4.6`.
2. We have two legacy PHP applications that use the legacy PHP version which comes standard with **CentOS7**, namely `php-5.4`.
3. We have one newer PHP application (Mediawiki) that needs newer PHP. So, I have installed `php71` alongside with `php-5.4`, using Remi repository.
4. I have switched Apache from `mod_php` to `php-fpm`.
5. I have followed some online instructions how to make both legacy `php-fpm-4.5` and the newer `php71-php-fpm-7.1` (from Remi) work simultaneously on Apache - to serve both the two legacy and one newer web applications.

**But my question still remains:** Why my legacy PHP Web applications still work fine without the package `php-mysql`?

Comment: Have you restart the FPM services after removing the extension ?

Comment: I had not. But now I did and - same result.

Comment: Check using a phpinfo page the extension loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access **MariaDB** or **MySQL** database, you need [mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [pdo_mysql](https://www.php.net/pdo_mysql) extension.

The old **php-mysql** package have runtime dependency on libmysqlclient (that is removed with mariadb-libs)

The alternative **php-mysqlnd** use the [PHP Native Driver](https://www.php.net/mysqlnd) and provides the same set of extension.

P.S.1. the mysql extension is deprecated and removed from PHP 7.

Comment: OK, I have php-pdo-5.4, so probably that is being used. So, apparently php-mysql has never actually been used and was there just because the old MariaDB dragged it in. Also, I have php71-php-mysqlnd which is most likely being used for the new PHP Web applications. Do I also need to install php71-php-pdo as well?

Comment: If you use PDO... of course you neeed php71-php-pdo... (for the extension) and php71-php-mysqlnd (for the driver)

Comment: I just found that "yum install php71-php-mysql" drags "php71-php-pdo" as a dependency, so the question is irrelevant. Thanks.